# mdbootstrap doesn't show image with php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mdbootstrap

I am working in project with mdb free + php.
I'm trying to fetch images from database and show them the image src get the path 
success but the image doesn't shown.
in the inspect element the image take "display :none !important" but I can't remove it.

This is my code:
[image]

Comment: Don't post code as an image. Copy/paste the code into your question.

Comment: Is your images folder located inside the folder you are now in?

Comment: Try accessing the image through browser and check the urls

Comment: I Tried accessing it from my browser it shows correctly but the problem Still

Comment: can you show hierarchy of your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all.
After many tries the problem solved when i disable adblocker.

Answer (score 1):

add this in your style.css  add it to the last line 
    if this not works reorder your style.css to just before your  tag closes think this solve ur problem

```
.deep-purple-skin img{
            display: block !important;
        }
```

Comment: I tried it but doesn't work and try to put it like 
<img src="images/<?php echo $img; ?>" alt="" style="display: block !important;">
But still disapear